# Cannot get Text from label jQuery, possible ID error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, label

If i use another ID to get some data, it's no problem, but when i use "lbl_BlendCalc_1.1_I" as an ID i cannot get the text. (Changed this ID is not possible).

```
<input id="yes1" type="checkbox">
<label style="width: 100px;" id="lbl_BlendCalc_1.1_I">test</label>

$('input').change(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        alert($("#lbl_BlendCalc_1.1_I").text()) ;
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wycvy/338/

I believe it is the ID that is doing something, but what i do not know.

Comment: Are you got the solution are not?

Comment: Do to the answer i'v got, yes, i figured it out. But StackOverflow, doesn't let me accept the answer until some time has passed.. so easy now ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attribute selector, giving id in quotes will escape the dot `.` that is reserved for class selector for jQuery.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wycvy/340/)

```
alert($("[id='lbl_BlendCalc_1.1_I']").text()) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

The character dot(.) is breaking the id. so if you dont want to change the id then escape it using backslashes '`\\`'.

Answer (score 1):

Id be broken if you using special characters like `@!.` So we need to escaping the special characters with two backslashes(`\\`).

```
$('input').change(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
        alert($("#lbl_BlendCalc_1\\.1_I").text()) ;
  }
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wycvy/339/)